# “Attempted to use Snappy compression, but Snappy is not installed” on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean

I have set up a new VPS via Digital Ocean and have installed MongoDB V4.2.8 on an Ubuntu server 18.04 release as per the official Mongo documentation. I'm using Compass version 1.21.2.

I have managed to bind the inbound and outbound IP addresses as well as configure the admin account for the database. However, when attempting to contact the database through Compass I am receiving the error

"An error occurred while loading navigation: Attempted to use Snappy compression, but Snappy is not installed. Install or disable Snappy compression and try again. "

[Image of Error within Compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoQCP.png)

As a shot in the dark, I then went and installed the snappy package from npm globally but this hasn't helped.

Anything I can do to fix this?